# Is it possible to get a tourist visa on arrival at Mumbai Airport?

Tags: visas, india, tourist-visas, visas-on-arrival

The instructions for getting an India visa online seem quite complicated. Is it possible to get a tourist visa at Mumbai Airport upon arrival?

*Note: This is for a Canadian citizen*

Comment: Could we know where the complications arise? The online process seems to be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 3):

No. According to [Visa Policy of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_India), only citizens of Japan are eligible for a visa-on-arrival in India (at the time of this writing).

Comment: You will have to apply for an e-visa, or apply at an Indian diplomatic mission for a tourist visa (which will almost certainly be harder than the e-visa).